# "gcloud beta builds triggers" error with the "--name" flag

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, beta

It is a very simple problem: I am using the following command:

```
gcloud beta builds triggers create github \
    --name="trigger_by_master_push" \
    --repo-owner="{REPO_OWNER}" \
    --repo-name="{REPO_NAME}" \
    --pull-request-pattern="^master$" \
    --build-config="cloudbuild.yaml"
```

With the structure given in the documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/builds/triggers/create/github)

Gives me the error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.builds.triggers.create.github) unrecognized arguments: --name=trigger_by_master_push (did you mean '--repo-name'?)
```

Comment: What's your `gcloud version`?

Comment: just found out it was a version problem, good question. a simple "gcloud components update" did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a version problem, since there was an update about Cloud Build trigger's name on GitHub on the [17th of August](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/release-notes#August_17_2020). I run the command with the `beta` component on version "2020.09.03" (gcloud SDK on 309.0.0) and it worked for me.

As you have noticed, the problem can be solved updating the `beta` component with:

```
gcloud components update
```